# Python Multithreading - How to control the number of parallel subprocesses?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

A multiprocessing noob here, I hope I am asking my question in a clear enough way.

I am using Python multiprocessing to parallelize a function that appends data to a text file from multiple sources. The execution order (and obtaining a lock) is not important in this scenario(as far as I understand) as the subprocesses can work completely independently from one another.

```
for municipality in municipalityDictionary.keys():
            proc = mp.Process(
                    target= f_unction,
                    args = (arg1, arg2, arg3)
            )
            procs.append(proc)  

for proc in procs:
            roc.start()

for proc in procs:
            roc.join()
```

However, this code creates a number of subprocesses equal to len(procs). What I am looking for a way to control the number of processes that are running in parallel (e.g.to have a multiprocessing.cpu_count() +/- n number of processed to which I'm feeding all the procs).

Also, all parallel functions take various amounts of time to execute so applying a proc.join() in batches of multiprocessing.cpu_count() results in having to wait for the slowest of all procs to complete before execution of the main process continues (fetching the next batch to .start() and .join().

I've read the Python multiprocessing documentation and went through multiple implementation examples  (including Manager(), Queue() & Pool()), but the examples I've seen are contextualized way differently and I don't get how to apply them to my use-case (it's probably me).

Thanks!

Comment: Pool will do it, i hope. Just use `with Pool() as pool:` `pool.starmap(func, args_tuples_list)`, where args_tuples_list is some iterable based on `municipalityDictionary` (you don't need to call `keys()` explicitly, python iterates over them) - I don't know how `arg1, arg2, arg3` are created in your code, but it might be `[(arg1_k1, arg2_k1, arg3_k1), ..., (arg1_kn, arg2_kn, arg3_kn)]`, where `argi_kj` denotes `argi` for key `kj`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your question is not completely clear and as a result I have included several code variations to try to cover what you may have intended.

Inspecting your code would lead one to believe that you were passing to each process the same values of `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` repeatedly, which may not be the case in reality. If it is the case, then the following code would achieve what you are after:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def main():
    worker = partial(f_function, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    # pool size is equal to multiprocessing.cpu_count():
    pool = Pool() 
    for municipality in municipalityDictionary:
        pool.apply_async(worker)
    # wait for all tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

# required by windows
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have used `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` to await the completion of all outstanding tasks. This is made possible because looking at your code you are not returning from `f_unction` any meaningful value you need to process in the main process. You will, however, not be able to detect any exceptions thrown by `f_unction`. Alternatively, you can save the `AsyncResult` instances returned by `apply_async` and call method `get` on them to block until the task is completed. This call can result in an exception if the task completed with an exception:

```py
    results = [pool.apply_async(worker) for municipality in municipalityDictionary]
    # wait for all tasks to complete:
    for result in results:
        result.get()
```

If you want to set a different pool size then specify `pool = Pool(pool_size)`.

If for each key in `municipalityDictionary` you had a different values of `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` to be used, then the following code should be used. But since it's not clear from your code where these values would be coming from or what relationship they have to the keys of `municipalityDictionary`, I am for demonstration purposes assuming that there is a list named `args` as follows:

```py
args = [[arg1_0, arg2_0, arg3_0], [arg1_1, arg2_1, arg3_1], ... [arg1_N, arg2_N, arg3_N]]
```

Since it does not appear that the keys of `municipality`, i.e. `municipality', are even being explicitly passed to` f_unction`, it seems reasonable that it should be the length of` args` that governs the number of tasks that need to be submitted. And so we have:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

args = [[arg1_0, arg2_0, arg3_0], [arg1_1, arg2_1, arg3_1], ... [arg1_N, arg2_N, arg3_N]]
    
def main():
    # pool size is equal to multiprocessing.cpu_count():
    pool = Pool() 
    pool.starmap(f_unction, args)

# required by windows
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If, however, each key of `municipalityDictionary` is a tuple that you want to unpack and pass to `f_unction`, then we have:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    # pool size is equal to multiprocessing.cpu_count():
    pool = Pool()
    pool.starmap(f_unction, municipalityDictionary.keys())

# required by windows
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```